# PHP NumberFormatter Slovenian spellout wrong

Tags: php, intl

I am trying to spellout an integer amount into Slovenian words (for postal declarations) using the NumberFormatter class from the intl package, but the result is completely wrong and makes no sense.

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter('sl', NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$fmt->format(561);
```

Results in "petsto šestdeset ena" while it should be "petsto enainšestdeset". Looks like baby talk instead.

In Croatian language, which is pretty similar, the result seems ok ("petsto šezdeset i jedan").

Is this a poorly done translation in PHP or is this based on my system locale? I'm on PHP 5.3.10 / Ubuntu 12.04.

EDIT:

intl is version 1.1.0, the current is 3.0.0, so maybe it has been fixed?

Comment: The translation is provided by the PHP `intl` extension. In my experience, some things are wrong now and then and get fixed in following releases. I get the same in PHP/5.5.5 / Windows 7 so it's probably a bug.

Comment: Álvaro thank you for testing it. I don't think it's a bug, but simply something that is not finished, e.g. in "dvjesto devetdeset šest" this "dvjesto" isn't even a Slovenian word, and ones always come before the tens, which is, I think, unique in slavic languages. I will report this on the PHP bug system.

Comment: Even on version 5.5.5 it looks like baby talk: `petsto šestdeset ena`. You will probably have to find alternative library or write yourown.

Comment: @Glavić can you check with phpinfo() which intl version do you have?
I couldn't file a report for my 5.3.10 because only 5.4 or 5.5 bugs should be reported, so I will report as if I were using your system.

Comment: @OmerSabic: intl version is 1.1.0, and ICU version is 51.2

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer - I don't speak Slovenian or Croatian.

It looks like there are some gaps in the patterns which the PHP extension uses for the numbers in these languages. To see what I mean, you can show the pattern used by running:

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter('sl', NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
echo $fmt->getPattern();
```

If you look at the output of this, you might spot one section of the "%spellout-cardinal-masculine:" which seems to jump from about 30 to 100.

```
...
    21: dvaset >%spellout-cardinal-masculine>;
    30: <%spellout-cardinal-masculine<deset;
    31: <%spellout-cardinal-masculine<deset >%spellout-cardinal-masculine>;
    100: sto;
    101: sto >%spellout-cardinal-masculine>;
    200: dvjesto;
...
```

This means there are no rules defined for the numbers above 31 and below 100. The '61' part of the number you are outputting falls into this gap.

You can generate your own pattern to fix this - I pasted in the pattern for the en-US formatter and fiddled it a bit so it looks like this:

```
...
    21: dvaset >%spellout-cardinal-masculine>;
    30: <%spellout-cardinal-masculine<deset;
    31: <%spellout-cardinal-masculine<deset >%spellout-cardinal-masculine>;
    40: forty;
    41: forty->%spellout-cardinal-masculine>;
    50: fifty;
    51: fifty->%spellout-cardinal-masculine>;
    60: sixty;
    61: sixty->%spellout-cardinal-masculine>;
    70: seventy;
    71: seventy->%spellout-cardinal-masculine>;
    80: eighty;
    81: eighty->%spellout-cardinal-masculine>;
    90: ninety;
    91: ninety->%spellout-cardinal-masculine>;
    100: sto;
    101: sto >%spellout-cardinal-masculine>;
    200: dvjesto;
...
```

Now if I save this in a new file called sl.txt with UTF-8 encoding, I can load it into the NumberFormatter:

```
$pattern = file_get_contents('sl.txt')
$fmt = new NumberFormatter('sl', NumberFormatter::PATTERN_RULEBASED, $pattern);
echo($fmt->format(561));
```

This gives me the following output:

```
petsto sixty-ena
```

Which is wrong, of course - it's a mixture of Slovenian and English, but I think if you edit the format to be something like this:

```
...
    61: >%spellout-cardinal-masculine>inšestdeset;
...
```

As I said, I don't speak Slovenian, so you probably want to check it. But this will give you the following output:

```
petsto enainšestdeset
```

You will need to add this rule for each of the missing number blocks from 31-100. You might also want to check the [ICU docs for rule based formatting](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classRuleBasedNumberFormat.html#details) to make sure you get it correct.

This is a bug, but not in PHP - if you would like to fix it then the issue is within [Unicode's Common Locale Data Repository](http://cldr.unicode.org/) in [this](http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/rbnf/sl.xml) file. PHP's intl uses ICU which uses the CLDR data.

Comment: Ahoy. Back then, I ended up rolling out my own function that does Slovenian spell-outs. However I still owe this to you. I have made fixes to the rule set, but the decimal one is giving me problems: if I load the ``NumberFormatter`` with the rule set, the constructor fails. This is the line that is making problems (under masculine)
``x.x: << vejica >%spellout-cardinal-feminine>;`` If I remove ``%spellout-cardinal-feminine`` from it, it's ok (but the spell-out is wrong). Here's the entire rule set: http://tauron.si/sl.txt